# java image compression and reduce bytes size

Tags: java, image, compression, resize

I developed a mass file up loader (a swing application) recently.One of the new requirements is to support uploading thousands of documents (GIF,JPG,PNG,DOCX,XLSX), each of these are like 3MB-10MB of size and we don't want to upload these huge files, we generally support TIFF files which has small byte size like 60KB-100KB. We are not concerned about the image quality, all we need to upload these docs for future reference. Right now I don't have any idea how to solve this problem, I started researching it. Please point me in right direction.

-PD

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would be to convert them to pdf files. Everything that can be printed can be converted to pdf. This also allows for image compression. Tiff won't be a good idea for doc/xls I think, it might make them bigger.

Answer (score 1):

a .doc or .xlsx can be gzipped very quickly for decent savings.

Images are more risky, depends on what the data is. Pictures of people? Pictures of text?